# PhpStorm: TS2304: Cannot find name X & other TS errors

Tags: typescript, caching, phpstorm

My IDE PhpStorm showed me within "**Problems**" in "**Current File**" and "**Project Errors**" a lot of
errors, mostly:

```
TS2034: Cannot find name [x]
TS1128: Declaration or statement expected
TS1005: "[x]" expected
```

and some others. But when I jumped to the source/line it was at the end of the file and googling for the first error, lead me to missing imports etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR;**

> PHPStorm -> File -> Invalidate Caches

Problem was, "Current File" just gave me one error and I did not make the connection, that  the IDE had a problem. When I saw, that "Project Errors" were over 40+, it was not so random anymore. There were simply unsed/old references from deleted functions etc.
So I searched for "phpstorm project errors shows deleted entries"
which gave me the right match:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/invalidate-caches.html

I thought this linking should be made here, if others search the fault within their code.